# Am I running out of RAM here?

Tags: macos, memory

This is me running out of RAM (according to me).

[image]

Green shows "Free" memory, 16 MB.

Blue shows "inactive" memory.

Does this mean I'm running out of RAM? Or just that I don't have more available and if needed the "inactive" will be taken?

Comment: If you're curious more about how Mac OS X uses memory you can check this answer I wrote on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/7585/is-there-a-way-to-get-osx-to-use-more-ram-and-lass-swap/7671#7671

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Free memory
>
> This memory is not being used
>   currently
>
> Wired memory
>
> This information can't be moved to
>   disk, so it must stay in RAM. The
>   amount depends on the applications you
>   are using.
>
> Active memory
>
> This information is currently in RAM
>   and has recently been used.
>
> Inactive memory
>
> This information has not recently been
>   used but will remain in RAM until
>   another application needs more memory
>   but no free memory is available. If
>   called upon by a process, this is
>   quickly changed to Active memory; if
>   it has been swapped to the hard disk,
>   it will be moved back to RAM and
>   marked as Active.

Bottom line: If more memory is required, you still have 'Blue' in reserve.

[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1342)

Comment: It looks odd that "free" and "inactive" are not even close to the same. Also, note, that there is 64.54 GB free virtual memory. Also (if I'm reading this right) there isn't a whole lot of paging going on, so you should be just fine.

Comment: That mean I'm using only 1.88 gb? :) :) I'm glad I have 1 gb "inactive" :) :) Thanks a lot.